# Django ReportLab 'list' object has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am trying to generate a pdf that will look like this:[image]

Here is my code:

```
doc = doc = SimpleDocTemplate(invoice_name)
flowable = []
flowable.append(Paragraph(invoice_name))
flowable.append(Paragraph(invoice_number))
flowable.append(Paragraph(invoice_date))
flowable.append(Spacer(1,4))

t = Table(table_data)
flowable.append(t)
flowable.append(Spacer(1,4))

flowable.append(Paragraph(comment_and_amount))

doc.build(flowable)
```

But I get this error: `'list' object has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of minor typos in this code, but the general form of the code is correct.

I have fixed all the typos, added the imports and added some data to make a working example:

```py
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table


invoice_name = "Test"

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf")
flowable = []
flowable.append(Paragraph(invoice_name))
flowable.append(Paragraph("1234"))
flowable.append(Paragraph("12/12/2023"))
flowable.append(Spacer(1,4))

table_data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
             ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
             ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
             ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]


t = Table(table_data)
flowable.append(t)
flowable.append(Spacer(1,4))

flowable.append(Paragraph("comment_and_amount"))

doc.build(flowable)
```

Comment: This works but my file keeps getting downloaded to the current file directory instead of making it downloadable on the browser.